# Apache Spark - NoSuchMethodException: <Class>.<init>(java.lang.String) when copying custom Transformer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I customized a toy estimator "SimpleIndexer" by following Holden Karau's tutorial at https://www.oreilly.com/learning/extend-spark-ml-for-your-own-modeltransformer-types. The problem is it error out when using it in "CrossValidator".

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ....SimpleIndexerModel.<init>(java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params$class.defaultCopy(params.scala:846)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.defaultCopy(Pipeline.scala:42)
    at com.nextperf.feature.SimpleIndexerModel.copy(SimpleIndexer.scala:63)
```

There is a similar questions asked before - [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <Class>.<init>(java.lang.String) when copying custom Transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352717/java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-class-initjava-lang-string-when-copying-c). Apparently the issue come from the "copy" method. But I tried the solution mentioned in the post, and it does not work.

- "SimpleIndexerModel" extends the DefaultParamsWritable trait
- Add a Companion object that extends the DefaultParamsReadable Interface

`class SimpleIndexerModel(override val uid: String, words: Array[String])
extends Model[SimpleIndexerModel] with SimpleIndexerParams with DefaultParamsWritable{
       ...
       ...
}
object SimpleIndexerModel extends DefaultParamsReadable[SimpleIndexerModel]`

The spark official implementation of this toy example is "StringIndexer". I cannot find a clue. Does anyone know why it happens, and how to fix the problem?

```
//"StringIndexerModel" works fine
val indexer1 = new StringIndexerModel("abc",Array("a"))
val m1 = indexer1.copy(new ParamMap())
//
//"SimpleIndexerModel" fails
val indexer2 = new SimpleIndexerModel("abc",Array("a"))
// This call throws the exception. 
val m2 = indexer2.copy(new ParamMap())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the implementation of Params.defaultCopy: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/param/params.scala#L845

This method requires a constructor with only one String parameter(uid). So you can resolve your problem by adding a constructor to your `SimpleIndexerModel` class.

```
def this(uid: String) = {...}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem! But I found Spark's "StringIndexerModel" model does not have `def this(uid: String) = {...}`,  it does have `def this(labels: Array[String]) = this(Identifiable.randomUID("strIdx"), labels)` however.

Comment: @user1269298 yes, but `StringIndexerModel` overrides `copy` method and doesn't call `defaultCopy` at all. You can also overrides `copy` method to avoid this issue.